# Is it grammatically incorrect to ask, " Whose own is this?"

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically incorrect to ask: "Whose own is this?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most definitely it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Why? Please tell me the reason.

Comment: Because ownership is a generic relationship, and therefore "whose," which implies that the relationship is exclusive, cannot apply. To put it a different way, who owns ownership? There may be some thought there struggling to be expressed, but, without a great deal more context being provided, it is impossible to give a more detailed response to this question.